# How to test for (ActiveRecord) object equality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, identity, equality

In `Ruby 1.9.2` on `Rails 3.0.3`, I'm attempting to test for object equality between two `Friend` (class inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`) objects.

The objects are equal, but the test fails:

```
Failure/Error: Friend.new(name: 'Bob').should eql(Friend.new(name: 'Bob'))

expected #<Friend id: nil, event_id: nil, name: 'Bob', created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
     got #<Friend id: nil, event_id: nil, name: 'Bob', created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

(compared using eql?)
```

Just for grins, I also test for object identity, which fails as I'd expect:

```
Failure/Error: Friend.new(name: 'Bob').should equal(Friend.new(name: 'Bob'))

expected #<Friend:2190028040> => #<Friend id: nil, event_id: nil, name: 'Bob', created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
     got #<Friend:2190195380> => #<Friend id: nil, event_id: nil, name: 'Bob', created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Compared using equal?, which compares object identity,
but expected and actual are not the same object. Use
'actual.should == expected' if you don't care about
object identity in this example.
```

Can someone explain to me why the first test for object equality fails, and how I can successfully assert those two objects are equal?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Rails deliberately delegates equality checks to the identity column. If you want to know if two AR objects contain the same stuff, compare the result of calling #attributes on both.

Comment: But in this case the identity column is `nil` for both instances because neither has been saved. `eql?()` checks both the value and the type of an attribute. `nil.class == nil.class` is `true` and `nil == nil` is `true`, so OP's first example should still have passed true. Your answer doesn't explain why it is returning false.

Comment: It doesn't just blindly compare ids, it only compares ids if the ids are meaningful. As mentioned in Andy Lindeman's answer: "New records are different from any other record by definition".

Answer (score 48):

Take a look at the [API docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveResource/Base/%3D%3D) on the `==` (alias `eql?`) operation for `ActiveRecord::Base`

> Returns true if comparison_object is the same exact object, or comparison_object is of the same type and self has an ID and it is equal to comparison_object.id.
>
> **Note that new records are different from any other record by definition**, unless the other record is the receiver itself. Besides, if you fetch existing records with select and leave the ID out, you’re on your own, this predicate will return false.
>
> Note also that destroying a record preserves its ID in the model instance, so deleted models are still comparable.

Comment: Updated API docs link for Rails 3.2.8 http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/frames

Also, noteworthy that `eql?` is overridden, but not the alias `equal?` which still compares `object_id`

Comment: This is really a better answer than the currently marked correct answer. The docs for `==` explained the gist of everything that I needed to know to figure out how rails was testing object equality.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to compare two model instances based on their attributes, you will probably want to *exclude* certain irrelevant attributes from your comparison, such as: `id`, `created_at`, and `updated_at`. (I would consider those to be more *metadata* about the record than part of the record's data itself.)

This might not matter when you are comparing two new (unsaved) records (since `id`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` will all be `nil` until saved), but I sometimes find it necessary to compare a *saved* object with an *unsaved* one (in which case == would give you false since nil != 5). Or I want to compare two *saved* objects to find out if they contain the same *data* (so the ActiveRecord `==` operator doesn't work, because it returns false if they have different `id`'s, even if they are otherwise identical).

My solution to this problem is to add something like this in the models that you want to be comparable using attributes:

```
  def self.attributes_to_ignore_when_comparing
    [:id, :created_at, :updated_at]
  end

  def identical?(other)
    self. attributes.except(*self.class.attributes_to_ignore_when_comparing.map(&:to_s)) ==
    other.attributes.except(*self.class.attributes_to_ignore_when_comparing.map(&:to_s))
  end
```

Then in my specs I can write such readable and succinct things as this:

```
Address.last.should be_identical(Address.new({city: 'City', country: 'USA'}))
```

I'm planning on forking the `active_record_attributes_equality` gem and changing it to use this behavior so that this can be more easily reused.

Some questions I have, though, include:

- Does such a gem already exist??
- What should the method be called? I don't think overriding the existing `==` operator is a good idea, so for now I'm calling it `identical?`. But maybe something like `practically_identical?` or `attributes_eql?` would be more accurate, since it's not checking if they're *strictly* identical (*some* of the attributes are allowed to be different.)...
- `attributes_to_ignore_when_comparing` is too verbose. Not that this will need to be explicitly added to each model if they want to use the gem's defaults. Maybe allow the default to be overridden with a class macro like `ignore_for_attributes_eql :last_signed_in_at, :updated_at`

Comments are welcome...

**Update**: Instead of forking the `active_record_attributes_equality`, I wrote a brand-new gem, **active_record_ignored_attributes**, available at http://github.com/TylerRick/active_record_ignored_attributes and http://rubygems.org/gems/active_record_ignored_attributes

Answer (score 2):

```
 META = [:id, :created_at, :updated_at, :interacted_at, :confirmed_at]

 def eql_attributes?(original,new)
   original = original.attributes.with_indifferent_access.except(*META)
   new = new.attributes.symbolize_keys.with_indifferent_access.except(*META)
   original == new
 end

 eql_attributes? attrs, attrs2
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a matcher on RSpec just for this type of comparison, very simple, but effective.

Inside this file:
`spec/support/matchers.rb`

You can implement this matcher...

```rb
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_clone_of do |model1|
  match do |model2|
    ignored_columns = %w[id created_at updated_at]
    model1.attributes.except(*ignored_columns) == model2.attributes.except(*ignored_columns)
  end
end
```

After that, you can use it when writing a spec, by the following way...

```rb
item = create(:item) # FactoryBot gem
item2 = item.dup

expect(item).to be_a_clone_of(item2)
# True
```

Useful links:

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-4/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot

Answer (score 1):

If like me you're looking for a **Minitest** answer to this question then here's a custom method that asserts that the attributes of two objects are equal.

It assumes that you always want to exclude the `id`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` attributes, but you can override that behaviour if you wish.

I like to keep my `test_helper.rb` clean so created a `test/shared/custom_assertions.rb` file with the following content.

```rb
module CustomAssertions
  def assert_attributes_equal(original, new, except: %i[id created_at updated_at])
    extractor = proc { |record| record.attributes.with_indifferent_access.except(*except) }
    assert_equal extractor.call(original), extractor.call(new)
  end
end
```

Then alter your `test_helper.rb` to include it so you can access it within your tests.

```rb
require 'shared/custom_assertions'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include CustomAssertions
end
```

Basic usage:

```rb
test 'comments should be equal' do
  assert_attributes_equal(Comment.first, Comment.second)
end
```

If you want to override the attributes it ignores then pass an array of strings or symbols with the `except` arg:

```rb
test 'comments should be equal' do
  assert_attributes_equal(
    Comment.first, 
    Comment.second, 
    except: %i[id created_at updated_at edited_at]
  )
end
```