# Failed RSpec test when comparing attributes that appear to be the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, pry

I am comparing two address objects in an RSpec test, but the test fails even though the attributes appear to be having the same values. I am using `expect(object1).to eq(object2)` and receive the following output:

```
Failures:

1) Property#address= sets all address fields
   Failure/Error: expect(property).to eq(property_address)

     expected: #<Property id: nil, property_type_id: nil, street: "780 Monterey Blvd", unit: "301", city: "San Francisco", state: "CA", zip: "94127", country: "US", square_feet: "906", beds: "2", baths: "1", floors: "1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 348>
          got: #<Property id: nil, property_type_id: nil, street: "780 Monterey Blvd", unit: "301", city: "San Francisco", state: "CA", zip: "94127", country: "US", square_feet: "906", beds: "2", baths: "1", floors: "1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 348>

     (compared using ==)

     Diff:
```

Using `pry-rescue` to look at the actual attributes and compare them, I receive the following:

```
[3] pry(RSpec::Expectations)> actual.attributes
=> {"id"=>nil,
 "property_type_id"=>nil,
 "street"=>"780 Monterey Blvd",
 "unit"=>"301",
 "city"=>"San Francisco",
 "state"=>"CA",
 "zip"=>"94127",
 "country"=>"US",
 "square_feet"=>"906",
 "beds"=>"2",
 "baths"=>"1",
 "floors"=>"1",
 "created_at"=>nil,
 "updated_at"=>nil,
 "user_id"=>335}
[4] pry(RSpec::Expectations)> expected.attributes
=> {"id"=>nil,
 "property_type_id"=>nil,
 "street"=>"780 Monterey Blvd",
 "unit"=>"301",
 "city"=>"San Francisco",
 "state"=>"CA",
 "zip"=>"94127",
 "country"=>"US",
 "square_feet"=>"906",
 "beds"=>"2",
 "baths"=>"1",
 "floors"=>"1",
 "created_at"=>nil,
 "updated_at"=>nil,
 "user_id"=>335}
[5] pry(RSpec::Expectations)> differ.diff(actual.attributes, expected.attributes)
=> "\e[0m\n\e[0m"
```

I can't spot any difference. Where is the `diff`-difference coming from?

**SOLUTION**
What through me off and why I hadn't followed the answer in [How to test for (ActiveRecord) object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738439/how-to-test-for-activerecord-object-equality), was the fact that while in `pry-rescue`, the output of
`differ.diff(actual.attributes, expected.attributes)` showed the same difference as the actual failed spec. However, following the answer for [How to test for (ActiveRecord) object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738439/how-to-test-for-activerecord-object-equality) I gave it a shot and changed the actual spec to use `expect(property.attributes).to eq(property_address.attributes)` and now the spec passes.

Comment: Can you post your test?

Comment: Has anyone written a custom equality method in Property?

Comment: `"\e[0m\n\e[0m"` looks like a string of non-printing characters (ANSI color escape sequences?)... I guess those are added by RSpec?