# Rails don't understand .include? behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of `characters` in `following`. Each `character` has a unique handle. I've checked the database to make sure there is only one `character` with the handle `barry1`. I'm trying to do:

```
following.include?(other_character)   # false
```

It's returning false, but I'm sure that `barry1` is in `following`. It thinks the `id`s are different, but there's only one `barry1`. What's going on?

**character.rb**

```
has_many :following, through: :active_follow_relationships,  source: :followed
```

**puts:**

```
puts following.first.handle    # barry1
puts other_character.handle    # barry1

puts following.first     # #<Character:0x007fef15231490>
puts other_character     # #<Character:0x007fef09bb4d58>

puts following.first.id    # 21
puts other_character.id    # 8
```

Comment: you have it in your solution following [21] is not other_character  [8]

Comment: Include won't work if objects are not the same. If you want to check inclusion by handle property, do: following.any? { |f| f.handle == other_character.handle }

Answer (score 0):

it seems that actually at least two different `characters` have the `handle` attribute with the value `barry1`. (cf ids 21 and 8). They are both persisted in a different place in memory and thus have two distinct ids.

If you want to check however that the collection `following` contains at least one `characters` with the `handle` attribute equal to `barry1` this should work:

`following.pluck(:handle).include? other_character.handle`

Comment: This is going to work fine but if he wants to use `following` later on, after check, rails will create two queries (first for plucking only the `:handle` column, second for `following` objects)

Comment: In the console `Character.find_by(handle: 'barry1')` only returns a single record. How is it possible for there to be a single record in the database but two records in memory?

Comment: That's because memory object is only representation of database object, you can create multiple variables (instances) of the same DB row and they won't be placed in the same memory spot. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738439/how-to-test-for-activerecord-object-equality

Comment: Indeed, the `find_by` method will return the first object that matches your search. 
You should check if it's the only one with : `Character.where(handle :'barry1')`