# The `==` method in Ruby on Rails with `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an event model that has a `has_and_belongs_to_many :users, inverse_of: nil`.

When I look at the event, I can see the user:

```
event.users.first
# => #<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('554daa95656c790b0e140000'), authentication_token: "U8wsVzXoPKfQ26TkZHSs", deleted_at: nil, email: "michael.jordan@nba.com", event_id: nil, first_name: "Michael", last_name: "Jordan", role_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('54d79542656c795581010000'), BSON::ObjectId('554dab81656c790b0e160000'), BSON::ObjectId('554db900656c790b0e1a0000')]>
```

I also loaded the user, and looked at her data:

```
user.first
# => #<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('554daa95656c790b0e140000'), authentication_token: "U8wsVzXoPKfQ26TkZHSs", deleted_at: nil, email: "michael.jordan@nba.com", event_id: nil, first_name: "Michael", last_name: "Jordan", role_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('54d79542656c795581010000'), BSON::ObjectId('554dab81656c790b0e160000'), BSON::ObjectId('554db900656c790b0e1a0000')]>
```

From what I see so far, I would say they are equal. But when I want to compare them with `==`, they are not equal:

```
event.users.first == user.first
# => false
```

I thought this may be because the `object_id` values are not the same:

```
event.users.first.object_id
# => 46965723447420
user.first.object_id
# => 46965766138560
```

I was not sure about how to analyse further. I simply extracted the user twice:

```
user1 = User.find("554daa95656c790b0e140000")
# => #<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('554daa95656c790b0e140000'), authentication_token: "U8wsVzXoPKfQ26TkZHSs", deleted_at: nil, email: "michael.jordan@nba.com", event_id: nil, first_name: "Michael", last_name: "Jordan", role_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('54d79542656c795581010000'), BSON::ObjectId('554dab81656c790b0e160000'), BSON::ObjectId('554db900656c790b0e1a0000')]>
user2 = User.find("554daa95656c790b0e140000")
# => #<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('554daa95656c790b0e140000'), authentication_token: "U8wsVzXoPKfQ26TkZHSs", deleted_at: nil, email: "michael.jordan@nba.com", event_id: nil, first_name: "Michael", last_name: "Jordan", role_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('54d79542656c795581010000'), BSON::ObjectId('554dab81656c790b0e160000'), BSON::ObjectId('554db900656c790b0e1a0000')]>
```

These two users compare to `true` with the `==` method:

```
user1 == user2
# => true
```

The `object_id` values are not the same:

```
user1.object_id
# => 46965753578080
user2.object_id
# => 46965753704780
```

Can someone help me understand why the `==` returns `false` in the first example but `true` in the second example?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4738485/1297435

Comment: I would need to update the question since I missed important information. I am not using ActiveRecord; I am using Mongoid. I will follow the suggestion/idea of the duplicate question and see if I can figure it out on my own. If not I'd come back and revise my question to add appropriate and more complete information. Thank you guys for your time.